# D3: How to load features from a JSON string in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have come across many examples of creating a JSON object from a JSON string with the JSON.parse(string) method, but how to load features of this object when using JSON.parse is not clear to me. For example, copying and pasting the text from the link below (json file: canada.topo.json), I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  path {
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 0.25px;
    fill: grey;
  }
</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var json = "jsonfile"
  jobj = JSON.parse(json)
  var width = 960,
    height = 1160;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
  //what to do next is my problem
  //A simple way to just project a map typically is with the following, which fails in this case:
  function(error, us) {
    svg.append("path")
    .data(jobj)
    //How do I load the features from the jobj object??
    .feature(us, us.objects.Canada).features
    .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));
  }
  //As a side point, this does not throw any errors, but nothing happens of course as there are no features
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    d3.select('.countries').selectAll('path')
    .data(jobj)
    svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));
</script>
```

QUESTION: How do I load features of the jobj into D3?

https://github.com/returnOfTheYeti/CanadaJSON/blob/master/canada.topo.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/returnOfTheYeti/CanadaJSON/blob/master/canada.topo.json this link it is link to the github page, not to your json file itself.

You should use this url -https://raw.githubusercontent.com/returnOfTheYeti/CanadaJSON/master/canada.topo.json You can get this url for any file by click on "Raw" button.

[image]

So with `d3.json` method you can load this file this way:

```
d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/returnOfTheYeti/CanadaJSON/master/canada.topo.json', function(data) {
    console.log(data); // <= object with loaded data
    console.log(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.Canada).features); // <= features
});
```

Check [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97j6utpm/1/).

**Update:**

In the case when you have json-string stored in some variable you can get features and create map this way:

```
var json = `...json string...`;

var jobj = JSON.parse(json); // parse string

var width = 960,
    height = 1160;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

// get features array with topojson.feature method, bind it with .data method and create map
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(topojson.feature(jobj, jobj.objects.Canada).features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));
```

Example with [your data](https://jsfiddle.net/levsha/7mfwc4mq/).

Comment: Although this is useful information, I am afraid this is not what OP is after. I think it's more about what the `.features` property is and how to obtain it.

Comment: @altocumulus Do you think so? Maybe I incorrect understand the question. My English not very well yet. If OP confirms that this answer not related to his question I remove it.

Comment: While this is helpful, I am more concerned with loading in the json specifically with "JSON.parse" (as a string, not a url) for computers with poor connectivity. I will clarify my question

Comment: @Rob Check my updated answer, please. Is it what you need?

Comment: Ah...yes, kind of embarrassingly simple! Thx for your patience.